# Evaluating an expression using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to evaluate a parameter using Matlab , here is the code

```
miu_not=1.257*1e-6; % permeability of free space
efslon_not=8.854*1e-12;% permittivity of free space
efslon_rg=input('Enter the relative permittivity of ground ') 
segma_g=input('Enter the ground conductivity') ; 
b=input('enter the conductor radius');
f= input('Enter the frequency');
w=2*pi*f;
prop_ground=sqrt(1i*w*miu_not(segma_g+(1i*w*efslon_not*efslon_rg)))
```

It is giving me an error regarding the indices for the last line that it must be positive or logic , while i don't have any array in the equation ???

The exact error message is:

```
Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.
Error in Untitled (line 8)
prop_ground=sqrt(1i*w*miu_not(segma_g+(1i*w*efslon_not*efslon_rg)))
```

Comment: Brackets are not for multiplication in MATLAB. Use `*` for normal matrix multiplication and `.*` for element-wise multiplication

Comment: When asking a question about an error message, please include the exact error, not your paraphrasing of the message.  As per @Ryan Lim's answer, you are missing a multiplication sign after `miu_not` in the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last statement

```
prop_ground=sqrt(1i*w*miu_not(segma_g+(1i*w*efslon_not*efslon_rg)))
```

is there supposed to be an operator between the miu_not and segma_g? 
I think it's evaluating to miu_not(%number%) so Matlab thinks you're trying to index miu_not by number.